# Insert rows based on value of multible columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table like this in my SQL Server database, only difference is the names and I have about 2 million rows with NULL values.

[image]

I need to update the company name with the correct name. How do I write a query which will insert the company name if address and zipcode both are found in another row where there is a company name?

This way I could update all the rows with address = 'address3' and zipcode = '3333' to 'Company3'. Only problem is i have 500 different companies, so making a manual update for each of the company names would take for ever! :)

Is there away to loop through each of the rows missing a company name and then search for the address and zipcode of that specific row in the same table and if it matches then it needs to update with the value of the company column on the matched row? :D

Comment: Using Microsoft SQL 2014

Comment: Is there any possibility that there may be multiple non-null values for a particular address and that they're different (e.g. Company4 and Company5 both listed against the same address). If so, how should that case be handled?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this in "standard" SQL is a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set company = (select max(t2.company)
                   from t t2
                   where t2.company is not null and
                         t2.address = t.address and
                         t2.zipcode = t.zipcode -- and perhaps country as well
                  )
    where company is null;
```

Depending on your database, there may be other ways to express this query as well.

Note:  If there are multiple companies at the same address then it chooses an arbitrary one (well, not arbitrary, the one with the maximum name lexicographically).

EDIT:

In SQL Server, you can write this with a `join`.  However, I like the idea of using window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(company) over (partition by address, zipcode) as thecompany
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set company = thecompany
    where company is null;
```

Comment: I could have the same address but in a different zipcode. Is this a problem? I only want to update when both the zip and address (streetname would be a better title) match

Comment: @TobiasKnudsen . . . That is why the `where` clause includes both `address` and `zipcode`.